# web3.py - web3.exceptions.BlockNotFound: Block with id:

Tags: web3js, web3.py, python

when i do loop, half of time i got error this `web3.py - web3.exceptions.BlockNotFound: Block with id:`

my code is like this

```
from web3 import Web3
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://polygon-rpc.com'))
w3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)

my_address = addresses[key]['MY_ADDRESS']
masterchef = w3.eth.contract(address=masterchef_address, abi=abi_masterchef) 
#master_chef
function_call = contract.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(amountA,amountBMin,[tokenA,tokenB],address,deadline)

transaction = function_call.buildTransaction(
    {
    "from" : address,
}
)
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
transaction, private_key=private_key
)
tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
```

it is similar with this question ([link](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/vrg4ul/web3py_web3exceptionsblocknotfound_block_with_id/))
the only difference is network and function.
idk what is problem, i guess the problem maybe block sync of latest block number
or because of this code `w3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)`

Comment: Have you asked in Polygon Discord about the issue? Because you are using Polygon RPC, it is Polygon's problem to provide support for their nodes.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa thanks for advice, as you said i was searching. but i couldn`t find any discord for dev, do you know where?